# Custom List Not Displaying in Android Studio

Tags: java

I am A total amatuer so forgive my language,I have a Test app which am using to test Functionality from tutorials online,The app gets a JSON feed from server,this part works fine,i am trying to display this feed in a custom listview,but when i test it,i dont get any error the page just stays blank,I have a class to create The custom view 
Adapter Class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class UserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserData>{

    private Context context;
    private List<UserData> users_list;

    public UserAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<UserData> objects) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context= context;
        this.users_list= objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View customview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);

        UserData userData=  users_list.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) customview.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        tv.setText(userData.getName());

        return customview;
    }
}
```

My main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity  {



    List<MyTask> tasks;

    List<UserData> userDataList;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        userDataList= new ArrayList<>();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.ac) {

            if (isOnline()) {
                requestData("http://192.168.1.3/database/getInfoDroid.php");

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void requestData(String uri) {
        MyTask task=new MyTask();
        task.execute(uri);
    }

    protected void updateDisplay(){
      UserAdapter adapter= new UserAdapter(this,R.layout.item_user,userDataList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    protected boolean isOnline(){
        ConnectivityManager cm= (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netinfo= cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(netinfo!= null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }



    }


    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"task started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(userDataList.size()==0) {

            }
        }


        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            System.out.print("Do in background ");

            String content =HttpManager.getData(objects[0].toString());
            System.out.print(content);
            return content;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {


            if (o.toString()==null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Cant connect to Web",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            userDataList= UserDataJsonParser.parseFeed(o.toString());
            updateDisplay();

        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object[] values) {
            //updateDisplay(values[0].toString());
        }
    }



}
```

So to me everything looks fine up until the updateDisplay method which is supposed to the name in listview:

```
 protected void updateDisplay(){
      UserAdapter adapter= new UserAdapter(this,R.layout.item_user,userDataList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: Try change this code `View customview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);` into `View customview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user, null, false);`

Comment: Still no luck,also i get a warning on that line says "Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter" if that helps

Comment: I see you check the json String content, but have you checked that userDataList is created properly by UserDataJsonParser.parseFeed()?

Comment: try update your listview in main Activity, not in AsyncTask?

Comment: ok before i could try anything,i get the" Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed." let me try and resolve this first

Comment: Need help sorting this out any suggestions??

Comment: @MrNeo you shouldn't pass null as parent when inflating views, and onPostExecute() is an appropriate place to update the ui.

Comment: i have posted a new question because now on the " Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed" i now get,code is the same .

Comment: In onMenuItemSelected() return false from the else block. Don't think it will solve the problem, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975140/attempted-to-finish-an-input-event-but-the-input-event-receiver-has-already-been, @FletcherJohns  please help me