# Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed

Tags: java, android

I am trying out a Tutorial i saw online,The app Gets and displays JSONfeed from server,this part works correctly,i am trying to display this feed in Custom listview but when i try to do so i get the "Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed" error in logcat and nothing happens in app,i have an adpter class:

```
public class UserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserData>{

    private Context context;
    private List<UserData> users_list;

    public UserAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<UserData> objects) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context= context;
        this.users_list= objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View customview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);

        UserData userData=  users_list.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) customview.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        tv.setText(userData.getName());

        return customview;
    }
}
```

My MainAtivity:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity  {



    List<MyTask> tasks;

    List<UserData> userDataList;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        userDataList= new ArrayList<>();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.ac) {

            if (isOnline()) {
                requestData("http://192.168.1.4/database/getInfoDroid.php");

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void requestData(String uri) {
        MyTask task=new MyTask();
        task.execute(uri);
    }

    protected void updateDisplay(){
      UserAdapter adapter= new UserAdapter(this,R.layout.item_user,userDataList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    protected boolean isOnline(){
        ConnectivityManager cm= (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netinfo= cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(netinfo!= null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }



    }


    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


        }


        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            System.out.print("Do in background ");

            String content =HttpManager.getData(objects[0].toString());
            System.out.print(content);
            return content;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {


            if (o.toString()==null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Cant connect to Web",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            userDataList= UserDataJsonParser.parseFeed(o.toString());
            System.out.print(userDataList);
            updateDisplay();

        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object[] values) {
            //updateDisplay(values[0].toString());
        }
    }



}
```

LogCat:

```
11-28 20:50:12.115 28063-28078/hilz.myapplication W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-28 20:50:12.115 28063-28078/hilz.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa50c8260, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-28 20:50:13.287 28063-28063/hilz.myapplication W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588750/attempted-to-finish-an-input-event-but-input-event-receiver-has-already-been-dis perhaps the answer here can help

Comment: There are lots of questions about this but none have selected a correct answer, so if you do solve it please post your answer. Here's a short blog I found: http://www.laurivan.com/attempted-to-finish-an-input-event/

Comment: Still no luck,have no idea how t solve this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your Public UserAdapter function, your super is not passing in the Objects.

It should be:

```
public UserAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<UserData> objects)
{
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context= context;
    this.users_list= objects;
}
```

and not:

```
public UserAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<UserData> objects)
{
    super(context, resource);
    this.context= context;
    this.users_list= objects;
}
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot man,thought i will never get a solution to this

Comment: @HilaryMwape If it solved your problem, please choose this as accepted answer.

Comment: Actually it didnt,i just thought it did at the time,had to restructure and i now use volley,i cant remember exactly what it chamged but i still had that problem